# Obtener contenido diferentes Fragments [Android]

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment

La cuestión es que hice una sección de código en donde tengo varios Fragments en la misma activity (tabbed activity) y quiero obtener información de las demás cajas de texto de los fragments anteriores en el último fragment (debido a que realizaré una transacción)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CÓDIGO CREADO

```
public class Perfil extends Fragment {

public Perfil() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Personal(), "Personal");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Direccion(), "Dirección");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Empresa(), "Empresa");

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}

private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> fragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitles.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String name) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitles.add(name);
    }
}
```

}

Los otros códigos(viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Personal(), "Personal");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Direccion(), "Dirección");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Empresa(), "Empresa");)
son fragments común y corrientes

Saludos

Comment: Cual es el código que has realizado? Revisar [ask]

Comment: He agregado el código. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si has definido un ID para cada campo de la forma `android:@+id/id` significa que los has agregado a la clase `R.java`, lo que significa que es accesible a través del método `findViewById(R.id.id)`.

Lo mejor igual sería que tus fragmentos tengan métodos públicos para obtener la información que quieres compartir, y que guardarad la referencia a esos fragmentos antes de agregarlos al `ViewPager`